# XSLT Mapping for replacing child nodes with new set under parent nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, mapping

I would like to have the below input converted to a specific output structure.

Scenario is to replace the duplicate nodes and values with a new set of nodes under the parent structure. Could you please help

Input

```
    <License>

            <LicenseType>SLN</LicenseType>

            <LicenseNumber>706909</LicenseNumber>

            <LicenseStateCode>TX</LicenseStateCode>

            <EffectiveDate>2999-12-31</EffectiveDate>

            <EffectiveDate>2999-12-32</EffectiveDate>

            <ExpiryDate>2014-10-25</ExpiryDate>

            <ExpiryDate>2015-02-01</ExpiryDate>

            <StatusCode>A</StatusCode>

            <StatusCode>A</StatusCode>

    </License>
```

Required Output

```
    <License>

            <LicenseType>SLN</LicenseType>

            <LicenseNumber>706909</LicenseNumber>

            <LicenseStateCode>TX</LicenseStateCode>

            <EffectiveDate>2999-12-31</EffectiveDate>

            <ExpiryDate>2014-10-25</ExpiryDate>

            <StatusCode>A</StatusCode>

    </License>

    <License>

            <LicenseType>SLN</LicenseType>

            <LicenseNumber>706909</LicenseNumber>

            <LicenseStateCode>TX</LicenseStateCode>

            <EffectiveDate>2999-12-32</EffectiveDate>

            <ExpiryDate>2014-10-25</ExpiryDate>

            <StatusCode>A</StatusCode>

    </License>
```

Comment: Can you please post your tried XSLT and tell us where you are facing the issue.

Comment: How do you know which ExpiryDate goes with which StatusCode (for example)?